# Verify python code with dependencies

Tags: python, linux, compilation

The Python project I'm working on consists of multiple classes / modules with focus on high code re-usability.

The problem I'm often faced with is: if one module is modified i.e. new parameter added to public method. How it can be verified that project still runs before the actual code is executed?

Is there a tool that can compile selected Python file and traverse through imported classes / methods and verify them as well?

Comment: Add some unittest in your code. Make sure pass all the tests when changing the code.

Comment: This is test project, majority of code are tests.